# Thread is being aborted

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2005

What exactly does all this mean below. I am running an asynchronous web request that calls a page that sends code to my database. Then my database fires off a stored procedure that runs into one of my SQL assemblies.  Most times it works, but sometimes I get this:

Thread was being aborted.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.

Source Error:

```
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

Stack Trace:

```
[ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.]
    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +486
    System.Web.ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error) +501
    System.Web.HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +123
    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) +379
```

Comment: The error is what is says. The thread executing the request was in the process of being aborted so your code won't be executed. You need to provide more details and a code sample to know why this is happening for you.

Comment: the problem is i'm not sure I know exactly where the code is, in the web app or my assembly?

Comment: when you say most of the time it running fine, how long will that take, it sounds like it's just running too slow or some resources been locked so the thread execution time hit the red line and so .net killed it

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting this error most likely is that you are getting timed out. Increase the ExecutionTimeout since at default its 110 seconds.

```
<compilation debug="false"></compilation>
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="1800"/> //1800 seconds / 30 minutes.
```

Here's an [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/aghausman/prevent-request-timeout-in-asp-net) that goes more into detail as to how to increase the ExecutionTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

The app domain could be getting recycled which can happen for a number of reasons.  That can cause a thread abort exception.

[Here is an article which explains some of the reasons for a recycle](http://www.treeloop.com/blog/iis-application-domain-and-pool-recycling)

If a process is long running, IIS/ASP.Net is not usually a good place to run it.

Comment: Can you add that reasons or for example link to further information, please?