# Tools to test out SQL Server assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio, assemblies

Are there any good tools to test out my SQL server assemblies?  I have two assemblies that get deployed to SQL Server 2005. The assemblies are created using VS 2008 and C#.Net. My web app makes request to a stored procedure that fires off the assemblies but sometimes it never returns. How do I test this?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166101/thread-is-being-aborted

Comment: how is this a duplicate?